# React Hooks: setState hook inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, setstate

Im currently wrestling with the async nature of setState with a form, my intended behaviour is that when the user clicks on the submitForm button it checks all the form values inside the state if that value is empty it then sets the errorState for that specific form element so that an error message appears

```
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    id: '',
    city: '',
    emailAddress:'',
    mobileNumber: ''
  });

  const [errors, setError] = React.useState({
    firstName: false,
    lastName: false,
    id: false,
    city: false,
    emailAddress: false,
    mobileNumber: false
  })

  const submitForm = () => {
    const setErrorArray = Object.keys(values).map((key) => {
      if (values[key] === '') {
        setError({...errors, [key]: true })
      }
    });
  }
```

I believe the issue is due to setState being async, so after the .map is done it sets only the last value inside the errors object to be true (thus errors.mobileNumber = true). Instead of making all the values that match the condition to be true. The spread operator {...errors} is overwriting the values to the initial false value.Is there anyway to achieve that each key inside errors is set to true if the value inside the values array is empty ??

Please any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Every time you call `setError` you do so with the same original `errors` and one new value. Why not build an object `newErrors` then do a single `setError({ ...errors, ...newErrors })` *after* the `.map`? Also note that a `.map` whose return value you don't actually use (in this case, an array of `undefined`) should be a `.forEach`.

Comment: You should check out `useReducer` as a possible solution to this issue.

Comment: You would be better off with using controlled inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd construct the whole new errors object at once by mapping the entries of the values, and then you can call `setError` with that object:

```js
const values = {
    firstName: 'first',
    lastName: 'last',
    id: '',
    city: '',
};
const newErrors = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(values).map(
    ([key, val]) => [key, val === '']
  )
);
console.log(newErrors);
// setError(newErrors);
```